# i been receiving this message: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. While doing some socket programming with the socket module on python

Tags: python, sockets, email, smtp

i am using the **socket module** and the **ssl module** from python, and i want to send an email using very basic socket programming, but every time i send a **command MAIL FROM, the message: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required appears**. I am looking for a solution that **does not use the smtplib module**.

this is the code:

```
from socket import *
import ssl



menssagem = '\r\n Eu gosto de redes'
finMenssagem = '\r\n.\r\n'
mailServer =  'smtp.gmail.com'
mailPort = 465
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with create_connection((mailServer, mailPort)) as sock:
 with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=mailServer) as clientSocket:
   print(clientSocket.version())
   recv = clientSocket.recv(1024).decode()
   print(recv)
   if recv[:3] != '220':
     print('220 reply not received from server.')
   heloCommand = 'HELO Alice\r\n'
   clientSocket.send(heloCommand.encode())
   recv1 = clientSocket.recv().decode()
   print(recv1)   
   if recv1[:3] != '250':
     print('250 reply not received from server.')
   mailfromCommand = 'MAIL FROM: <arthursilvamatias@gmail.com>\r\n'      
   clientSocket.send(mailfromCommand.encode())
   recv2 = clientSocket.recv().decode()
   print(recv2)
```

Image o the code running:
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhdsu.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to send outbound email using Gmail's service.

They are trying to protect your account by preventing unauthorized users from using it to send email, masquerading as you.

This link should explain what you need to do to authenticate: https://stackabuse.com/how-to-send-emails-with-gmail-using-python/#:%7E:text=As%20for%20the%20actual%20Python,com%27%2C%20465)%20server.

Comment: thanks for the answer!!!, but google doesn't allow permission for less secure apps anymore since march of this year, and i am trying not use the smtplib as mentioned above.